# Splitting String by Regex

Tags: java, regex

I've got this string here: `M412 Rex | -HEADSHOT-`. I want to split it on the `|` to get the first name, however my code is not working as intended.

```
        System.out.println("weaponPart = " + weaponPart);
        String[] weaponPartParts = weaponPart.split(" | ");
        for (String s : weaponPartParts) {
            System.out.println("s = " + s);
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Prints out:

```
weaponPart = M412 Rex | -HEADSHOT-
s = M412
s = Rex
s = |
s = -HEADSHOT-
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the regex matching, but what is actually going on?

Comment: The `| ` is a special regex char. Have you tried `" \\| "`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must double escape the `|` that is a special character in a regex: `\\|`. *(It means "OR")*

In other words, your actual pattern means *"split when you find a space OR a space"*.

Thus the good line is:

```
String[] weaponPartParts = weaponPart.split(" \\| ");
```

As an aside comment these special characters `\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .` are the "Dirty Dozen".

Answer (score 2):

User `\\|` instead of `|`

Change

```
String[] weaponPartParts = weaponPart.split("|");
```

to

```
String[] weaponPartParts = weaponPart.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also using the `Pattern.quote` method to escape any special characters:

```
String[] weaponPartParts = weaponPart.split(Pattern.quote(" | "));
```

From the **[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)**:

> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern
>   that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> **Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given
>   no special meaning.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the |, what I mean is..

```
String[] weaponPartParts = weaponPart.split(" \\| ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String weaponPart = "M412 Rex | -HEADSHOT-";
System.out.println("First Name::"+weaponPart.split("\\|")[0]);
```